# How to subscribe to changes in feature module in NgRx?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using `AoT`, `and lazy-loading`. I am trying to lazy load my store modules as well. my problem is when I subscribe to feature module I get 'undefined' instead of getting the store data, using Redux dev tools, I can see that the feature is lazily loaded and populated with data properly.

this my appState reducer,

```
export interface AppState {
  auth: fromAuth.State;
  httpAction: fromHttpActions.State;
  Geo: fromGeoActions.State;
  UI: fromUI.State;
  DbSearch: fromDbSearch.State;
  LocationSearch: fromlocationSearchReducer.State;
  AppDropdownList: fromdropdownReducer.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  auth: authReducer,
  httpAction: httpActionReducer,
  Geo: geoReducer,
  UI: userInterfaceReducer,
  DbSearch: dbSearchReducer,
  LocationSearch: locationSearchReducer,
  AppDropdownList: dropdownReducer
};
```

and I inject it in my main app-module as following,

```
StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
```

the above modules are working perfectly,

the problem is in the following,

```
export interface IRegistryState {
  patientRegistration: frompatientRegistrationReducer.State;
}
export const registryReducers: ActionReducerMap<IRegistryState> = {
  patientRegistration: patientRegistrationReducer
};
```

and I inject it in the feature-module as following,

```
StoreModule.forFeature('registryStore', registryReducers),
```

when I do the following, the returned value is always undefined

```
  this.registryStore.select(s => s.patientRegistration).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding `createFeatureSelector` to my AppState Module `const getRegistryState`.
so after creating the feature store module I needed to add the following charm to my AppStore Module,

```
export interface AppState {
  auth: fromAuth.State;
  httpAction: fromHttpActions.State;
  Geo: fromGeoActions.State;
  UI: fromUI.State;
  DbSearch: fromDbSearch.State;
  LocationSearch: fromlocationSearchReducer.State;
  AppDropdownList: fromdropdownReducer.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  auth: authReducer,
  httpAction: httpActionReducer,
  Geo: geoReducer,
  UI: userInterfaceReducer,
  DbSearch: dbSearchReducer,
  LocationSearch: locationSearchReducer,
  AppDropdownList: dropdownReducer
};
export const getRegistryState = createFeatureSelector<IRegistryState>(
  'registryStore'
);
```

and in the component you still call AppState Store and you select the feature selector as following,

```
this.appStore
          .select(fromApp.getRegistryState)
          .map(data => data.patientRegistration)
          .subscribe(data => {
            if (data.loaded) {
              this.patientRestration.patchValue(data.patientData);
              console.log(data.patientData);
            }
          });
```

Comment: I see one problem in this answer. To create feature selector with type `IRegistryState` you need to import that type from lazy loaded module. Hence you loose lazy loading.Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm facing the same problem.